# Styled-components react native - Text Input onBlur not working

Tags: react-native, styled-components

I'm fairly new to styled-components in react native. I'm creating a custom TextInput component. I want to add an event of onBlur to change a piece of state. However onBlur is never triggered.

```js
import React, { useCallback } from 'react'

const TextField = styled.TextField`
    margin-top: 6px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: '#000';
    padding: 16px 15px;
    border: 0.8px solid;
    background-color: '#fff';
`


const Input = ({
    editable,
    ...rest
  }) => {

    const handleOnFocus = useCallback(() => {
        console.log('focus')
    }, [])

    const handleOnBlur = useCallback(() => {
        console.log('blur')
    }, [])

    return (
        <TextField
            onFocus={handleOnFocus}
            onBlur={handleOnBlur}
            editable={editable}
            {...rest}
        />
    )
}



export default Input
```

Comment: How do you know that `onBlur` is not called ... steps you do?

Comment: cause i put a console logs to see if the handleOnBlur is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my issue. It's a stupid mistake. Happened to be passing the prop onBlur to the Input component which was overriding the onBlur I was trying to set on the TextField styled-component.

Answer (score 0):

as per guidelines of Textinput in
[React Native Textinput](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#editable)

`editable` should be true to called blur, because if your input is editable is false then you can not focus that element and without focused element `onBlur` never triggered.

Comment: Editable is set to true onBlur still doesn't trigger. However, focus does trigger.

Comment: ok, @themaster can you please inform me what you doing to be triggered onBlur().

Comment: I am pressing the text input so it focuses then I press another text input. So the first input loses focus and second input focuses. But the blur function is never triggered

Comment: @themaster it should be worked, can you please share more information or any example, there might be any conflicts with design.